# How to preload select options?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have something like this. It is a fonts selector in a dropdown:

```
<select style='font-family:Satisfy' placeholder="Satisfy" ng-model="fontFamily" ng-change="changeFont(fontFamily, $event)">
  <option rel='preload' style='font-size:20px'
    ng-repeat="(i,font) in fonts.paginator.currentItems"
    ng-style="{ 'font-family':  font.family }"
    selected="0">{{font.family }}</option>
</select>
```

The problem with this is that then user press on the dropdown only then all the woff files are downloaded, so user experiences a lag until it is done. How to preload these options before user clicks on the dropdown?

Comment: You can make bunch of GET requests in background, maybe on app bootstrap and make fonts cached.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle or plunker with your controller code ?

Comment: Just fetch them in the controller first and bind them to the $scope object? You can also use `ngInit` to load the fonts first but you should handle this in the controller instead really.